# Read stdin and pass through pipeline to tee

Tags: shell, pipe, tee

I'm playing around with `xinput` to watch keyboard events.
I'd like to transform the output with `awk` and pass it to `tee`, printing to stdout and writing to a file simultaneously.

I watch events on device 14, type a single <kbd>Space</kbd>, then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit:

```
$ xinput test 14
key release 36
key press   65
 key release 65
key press   37
key press   54
^C
```

I can transform this with `awk`:

```
$ xinput test 14 | awk '{ print $NF }'
36
65
 65
37
54
^C
```

Or I can pipe it to `tee`:

```
$ xinput test 14 | tee a.log
key release 36
key press   65
 key release 65
key press   37
key press   54
^C

$ cat a.log
key release 36
key press   65
 key release 65
key press   37
key press   54
```

But I can't pipe the transformed output to `tee`:

```
$ xinput test 14 | awk '{ print $NF }' | tee b.log
^C

$ cat b.log
```

---

I think I understand what's going on, and can boil it down to a simpler example where I `cat` stdin to `tr` and pipe that to `tee`.

```
$ cat | tr a x | tee x.log
```

If I type <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the pipeline aborts before printing to stdout or writing to `x.log` (though the file itself is created):

```
ab
^C

$ cat x.log
```

If I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, an `EOF` character signals the end of input, and output gets printed to stdout and written to `x.log`:

```
ab
xb

$ cat x.log
xb
```

---

I've tried a couple different approaches, but so far no success.

```
$ { xinput test 14 | awk '{ print $NF }' ; } > >(tee x.log)

$ exec {fd}> >(tee x.log)
$ xinput test 14 | awk '{ print $NF }' >& ${fd}
$ exec {fd}>&-

$ exec > >(tee x.log)
$ xinput test 14 | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions.

1. Use `stdbuf` to run `awk` with no output buffering.

   `xinput test 14 | stdbuf -o0 awk '{ print $NF }' | tee b.log`
2. Add `system("")` call within the `awk` script

   `xinput test 14 | awk '{ print $NF; system("") }' | tee b.log`